# How to use sbatch with a docker container that holds a snakemake pipeline?

Tags: docker, snakemake, hpc, sbatch, apptainer

I am building a Snakemake pipeline that I am going to put in a container. I want users to be able to pull the container using Apptainer or Docker. I would also like users to be able to run the container locally or using SBATCH. I know that there are ways to get [Snakemake](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/executing/cluster.html) to run with SBATCH, and there are ways to do the same with [Apptainer](https://apptainer.org/docs/user/main/mpi.html#batch-scheduler-slurm). But if I am wrapping my Snakemake in a container should I run both of them with SBATCH commands, or just the container?